# Anaconda offline - can't import installed package

Tags: python, anaconda

I am working with an install of Anaconda on an offline server and want to install some third party packages.

1) Download the conda PACKAGE.tar.bz2 file to local desktop machine
2) SCP it into my home directory on the server
3) On the server, activate a Conda environment, using *my* Anaconda binary
4) On the server, run `conda install PACKAGE.tar.bz2`

Even though this runs without error, Anaconda cannot find PACKAGE when I try to import it. I think the problem is due to the channel being "unknown".

For example, I tried to install Pyproj in my local environment.

```
(testenv) [user@server ~]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda2/envs/testenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anaconda                  5.2.0                    py27_3
pyproj                    1.9.5.1                  py27_0    <unknown>
```

Anaconda sees that it has been installed in `testenv` but cannot import it.

Is there some flags I need to use when installing the package? Is there a way to define the channel for Pyproj? Other solutions?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Install works if I am in the *base* environment. But it does not work if I try to install a package directly into one my user-defined environments.

Comment: What is the output of `which python` when you've activated your `testenv`?

Comment: It is using the version I installed in my home directory `~/anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: That's the problem. You have to install Python to your environment `testenv` as well.

Comment: Oooohhhhh I see. So when I created the environment using `conda create -n testenv anaconda`, I told it to use the base anaconda Python install, and all its dependencies. So packages installed in the environment cannot be located.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it! I Thank you